# What does 'train NLL' and 'test NLL' mean?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology

I've just started reading ML papers and occasionally I encounter the word 'train NLL' and 'test NLL', which I cannot figure out the meaning. What does they mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NLL is an abbreviation for "negative log likelihood".

It serves the same purpose as the Maximum Log Likelihood. However, since most optimization problems typically attempt to minimize a function, the negative log likelihood is what is preferred to the Maximum Log likelihood.

Comment: as it stands, this answer is quite short by CV standards and would be more appropriate as a comment to the original question. Maybe you could explain what the likelihood function is.

Comment: I've extended the answer to provide more information, however the original question seemed to be based on not know what the abbreviation stood for.

Comment: yes, it looks like the original poster doesn't know what a likelihood function is. That's exactly why I suggested you to explain that (which is different from just saying why neg log is used instead of max log).